# eclipse does not make class file of my java class

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a project which has 20 classes among all of these classes there is one EntitySorted.java which Eclipse can not make EntitySorted.class for that so when I run the project I get the following error:

Entity cannot be resolved to a type  here is the snap shot of error:

[image]
[image]

I searched a lot but I got nothing can anyone help?

also this the list of my java file if you note you will see the small arrow beside EntitySorted.java which shows it is not compiled(I am right)

[image]

Comment: A screenshot or something would be helpful :p

Comment: When you save `Entity.java` is there any red markings?  Do you have any evidence od successful compilation?

Comment: Is Entity.java saved in a `source` folder?

Comment: It's probably an unknown entity....

Comment: Eclipse differentiates between source folders and non-source folders. Is `Entity.java` in the same folder as other Java files which do compile?

Comment: This message means that some other class (referenced in the complete error message that you should have posted) tries to use the Entity class without having imported it. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: @JBNizet if the class is indeed not generated then it may be hard to reference it, even when using an `import` statement...

Comment: The error happens in entityBar.jsp. What's the code of this JSP? Does it contain import statements?

Comment: I don't import any class I just use EntitySorted.java as a type and I don't get any error until I run it

Comment: That's the problem. You must use the fully qualified name of the class (`omid.common.data.EntitySorted`) in your JSP, or you must import it to be able to simply use `EntitySorted`. Now google for "import in JSP", and then google for "why should I avoid scriptlets in JSPs".

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood the importing I do use importing as follow <%@ page import="omid.common.data.*" %>

Comment: One more thing I checked the list of all *.class files and I could not find EntitySorted.java

Comment: For some reason my tomcat7 stopped working so I installed tomcat6 can it be because of that?

Comment: I added stacktrace of the error as an image above it may help

Comment: What's actually responsible for generating the class files? By the looks of it this is a Maven project as well.

Comment: So you mean it is because of maven!